# How can i correct the error inside for loop(it says print func cant return any value)?

Tags: python

```
def generate_ticket(airline, source, destination, no_of_passengers):

    if no_of_passengers <= 5 :
        ticket_number_list = [""]*no_of_passengers
        for i in range(0, no_of_passengers):
            ticket_number_list[i] = print("'",airline,":",source[0:3],":",destination[0:3],":",(101+i),"'",",")
    else:
        ticket_number_list = [""]*5
        for j in range(0,5):
            ticket_number_list[j]=print("'",airline,":",source[0:3],":",destination[0:3],":",(101+j+(no_of_passengers-5)),"'",",")

    return ticket_number_list
print(generate_ticket("AI", "Bangalore", "London", 3))
```

Comment: It works fine for me after fixing the indentation

Comment: `print` does not return anything.

Comment: How? Indentation is already fixed i think@Bazingaa

Comment: how can i fix it? @mad_

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
ticket_number_list[i] = print("'",airline,":",source[0:3],":",destination[0:3],":",(101+i),"'",",")
```

`print` does not return any value, nothing is stored in `ticket_number_list`. Use instead:

```
ticket_number_list[i] = "'" + airline + ":" + source[0:3] + ":" + destination[0:3] + ":" + (101+i) + "' "
```

Same for `ticket_number_list[j]`

Answer (score 0):

`print` does not return string object. you need to concatenate using `+`

```
def generate_ticket(airline, source, destination, no_of_passengers):

    if no_of_passengers <= 5 :
        ticket_number_list = [""]*no_of_passengers
        for i in range(0, no_of_passengers):
            ticket_number_list[i] =  "'{}:{}:{}:{}',".format(airline,source[0:3],destination[0:3],(101+i)) 
    else:
        ticket_number_list = [""]*5
        for j in range(0,5):
            ticket_number_list[j]= "'{}:{}:{}:{}',".format(airline,source[0:3],destination[0:3],(101+j+(no_of_passengers-5))) 

    return ticket_number_list
print(generate_ticket("AI", "Bangalore", "London", 3))
```

**Output**

```
["'AI:Ban:Lon:101',", "'AI:Ban:Lon:102',", "'AI:Ban:Lon:103',"]
```